# J2EE : saving pictures inside the application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am working on a J2EE application in which I need to save user's pictures. my question is where should I save these pictures ?  knowing that I want to use a relative path .

NB : I am using glassfish as server .

Comment: use a DB or some particular folder on server

Comment: you can save the images in following location:   webapp/images/users/<userid>. Within code webapp path value can be retrieved using String webapppath = ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");

Comment: Load a `.properties` file from your classpath that points you to a location on the server to store the images.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice here is to save the image inside your web application under web content (make a separate folder) , in this way you will be able to render images in other browsers also (not just in eclipse default's)
and you need to save the complete path of the image into database.

eg : e:\workspace\projectname\webcontent\pic\image.jpg

NB : never store image in database